# I don't have the IIS Express button when i first startup Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I just installed Visual Studio 2019 and I've been following on how to make a new project, and after I create the new project I don't have the IIS Express button but instead get "select startup item"

Comment: sounds to me like you did not create some kind of web project, but created a class or some other type of project.

Comment: i created a web project, i asked my tutor for help but even he didn't know what the issue was, I've reinstalled it vs a couple times but the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

I mean, if I created a new asp.net (web forms), then you should be able to open the properties for that project.

So, from menu, we go:

[image]

And then you can go to web tab,

Say like this:
[image]

And then of course you should see this:

[image]